# ID of the transaction that inserted a row on Amazon Redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I need to know the ID of the transaction that inserted a row.

On vanilla postgres I could do:

`SELECT xmin from <table>`

But on Redshift that gives:

`ERROR: column xmin does not exist in <table>`

Is there a way to get what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no auto incremented column by default in Redshift, I would say recreate that table with an extra column. That new column should be an IDENTITY column. You should not insert anything in that column. It will automatically be populated incrementally every time you insert a row. It will be unique for each row so you can use that column as row_id.

Here is how your DDL should be:

```
CREATE TABLE <schema>.<table_name>
(
    row_id BIGINT IDENTITY (0,1),
    ....
)
```

Now insert rows from your old table into this. Again, don't assign any value to row_id column. (It will give you an error) You will see that it is automatically populated.